# Hyperledger fabric changing endorsement policy : stateBasedValidator.Validate failed

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to change endorsement policy in existing setup at chaincode level for that I have changed the chaincode sequece and approved chaincode for all organizaiton. I have commited the chaincode successfully and I'm able to perform transaction successfully.

but when I tried same steps once again for rechanging the endorsement policy for that I have commited chaincode without any issue but while I'm performing the transaction I'm getting following error.

```
2021-08-17 09:16:51.375 UTC [vscc] Validate -> ERRO 0aa VSCC error: stateBasedValidator.Validate failed, err validation of endorsement policy for chaincode basic in tx 110:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy
2021-08-17 09:16:51.376 UTC [committer.txvalidator] validateTx -> ERRO 0ab Dispatch for transaction txId = 79f0fa71cc39d61d56f565bec88856ca6899067401fc309ea40d302c66b37dcb returned error: validation of endorsement policy for chaincode basic in tx 110:0 failed: signature set did not satisfy policy
```

My default policy mentioned in configtx.yaml file is:

```
Policies:
    Readers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "MAJORITY Admins"
    LifecycleEndorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "AND('Org1.peer', 'Org2.peer', 'Org3.peer')"
    Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "AND('Org1.peer', 'Org2.peer', 'Org3.peer')"

Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
```

during the approve the chaincode for organizations and commit I have used signature policy as

> --signature-policy "OR('Org1.peer', 'Org2.peer', 'Org3.peer')"

Comment: Did you get all the required endorsements ? I would not expect the new policy to take effect until it's validated and committed governed by the existing policy

Comment: even I'm making all the three organizations as part of endorsement policy then also I'm getting same error. so we can not assume that previous policy is taking effect.

Comment: So just to confirm, you got endorsements for the update from all 3 orgs correct ?

Comment: yes I got the endorsement for all the 3 organizations for commiting the chaincode.

Comment: I've tested the same scenario with success. Changed endorsement policy a few times and each time got validations/invalidations as expected when endorsing with different org peers.

Comment: are you able to perform a transactions after every updation of the endorsement policy? because in my case after first updation it is working fine but after second updation it is failing.

Comment: Yes, works for me.